# Create a URL based on Selection in <ul> <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, deployment

I am trying to build url based on a user selection from a multilevel list.
The user selects four options which in turn will create the url required for retrieval of a document.

Example:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Report name</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Year</a>
            <ul>
           <li><a href="#">2010</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li>Jan</li>
                     <li>Feb</li>
                     <li>March</li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2014</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
</li>

<!-- etc. -->

</ul>
```

So I would select the Report Name > Year > Month and this would build a url which equals the path to the file.

e.g. http://www.example.com/Report1/2010/Jan

Does anyone perhaps have any ideas as to how this can be done.

Comment: You either need to use the cookie to save the user input or you can use a hidden field with the ID to get this done. Keep on extracting the data whenever there is a change. You need to handle the scenario to restrict user from making a selection in an orderly fashion otherwise the user will be able to make selection at his will which will mess up all the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are several options, I would suggest using javascript.

So, basically, you would check if an `<li>` was clicked and if it was, then add a certain value to string, the redirect the page using that built string.  Here is an example of what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/35XDn/4/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of `$(this)` being used to get the value of what was clicked. I'm using JQuery in this example.

Had to add an `id` to the year value. You don't HAVE to do it this way, you can use the jquery selectors to get the proper value. It is just a lot easier.

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Report name</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Year</a>
            <ul>
           <li id='2010'><a href="#">2010</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li>Jan</li>
                     <li>Feb</li>
                     <li>March</li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2014</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
</li>

<!-- etc. -->

</ul>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
```

The javascript looks like this:

```
$('#2010 li').click(function()
                    {
                        var year=$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
                        var month=$(this).text();
                        console.log(month+' '+year);
                        //this will show you Jan and 2010 in the log. You can use this variable to append to a URL string.
                    });
```